# why Wpf TreeView collapse action changes selection?

Tags: wpf

I have a wpf TreeView with mvvm object binded.
when I have a **child node selected** and I collapse the parent node, the parrent node get selected. When I expand the parent again, the parent retains the selection.
I want Windows Explorer behavior where when I collapse the parent, the parent shows highlight visual but never gets selection and when I expand it again, the original child shows its selection.

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/81948.aspx/1) thread asks the same question, and the answer given is that this is the expected behaviour. I disagree.

Still looking for a solution, myself.